# Conservation of momentum (angular and translational)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics

A ring of radius $R$ and mass $M$ lies on its side on a frictionless table. A bug of mass $m$ rests on the ring. The bug starts walking on the ring with constant speed $v$ relative to the ring. Describe the motion of ring relative to ground frame.

(In some questions the ring is being pivoted, but not here, ring is free to move any way horizontally).

Comment: Hi Nitin and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Physics Stack Exchange isn't a homework help site; but, if you do want that kind of help you can take a look at [this thread for a list of free online homework help resources](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh).

Answer (score 1):

Use conservation of angular momentum relative to the center of the ring. Since both the ring and the bug were initially at rest, the angular momentum of the system about the center of the ring was zero. Since no external torque is acting on the system, angular momentum of the system must remain zero even when the bug starts moving along the rim. How should the ring move for this condition to be satisfied?

Comment: do centre of ring move or not ? if move what type of path that follow, do they follow circular (what would be the radius?).

Comment: It's better if you draw a diagram of the situation. The bug is sitting on the rim of a hoop. I presume the surface on which the hoop is resting is frictionless. If the bug starts to move along the rim of the hoop, how should the ring rotate? Imagine a vertical axis passing through the center of the circle/hoop/ring. Now think about the direction in which the ring must rotate to conserve the angular momentum about the vertical axis.

Comment: I don't want to explicitly state the answer because this is something you yourself must work out to gain a better insight.

Comment: http://se.u.94y.info for a list of potentially helpful resources if this reply doesn't suffice.

Comment: as center of mass(ring + bug) must not move, how ring rotates such a way

Comment: You are correct. Center of mass must remain at rest since no external forces are acting on the system. Consider a merry-go-round. You are standing near its edge. Both you and the merry-go-round are stationary. Now, you start walking in counter-clockwise (or, clockwise) direction, with some velocity, $v$. In what direction would the merry-go-round rotate to keep the Angular momentum equal to it's initial value of zero?